Cofibrant replacement in Serre-Quillen model structure on Top
In the Hurewicz-Strøm model structure on $\mathrm{Top}$ there is a very straight forward cofibrant replacement for a map $f\colon A\to X$, namely by replacing $X$ with its mapping cylinder $A\to M(f)$. Is there a nice way of doing something similar in the Serre-Quillen model structure on $\mathrm{Top}$? (Of course there is the factorisation given by the small object argument, but it does not seem particularly enlightening. Another vage thought I had is to do something with CW-approximation and mapping cylinder, as we know that relative cell complexes are the cofibrations in this model structure, but I did not get anything meaningful.)

One can replace $A \rightarrow X$ by a map of CW complexes, say by taking $|\mathrm{Sing(-)}|$, and then the mapping cylinder of this gives such a replacement.

Also, is there an alternative explanation, why this yields exactly a cofibrant replacement, based on the Quillen equivalence between the Serre-Quillen model structures on topological spaces and the Quillen model structure on simplicial sets?

Hi @connor-malin, thanks a lot for your quick answer. Just to make sure I follow the logic: we know that cofibrant objects under the Serre-Quillen model structure are cell complexes (relative empty set), right? Now we can construct M([Singf|)
as a cell complex by first constructing |SingX|
which is CW and then on it |SingA|×[0,1]
, which is a CW complex since [0,1]
is compactly generated. So M([Singf|)
is indeed a cofibrant object. Is that right?

Hmm, I don't have a detailed argument in mind. It is just known that the mapping cylinder of a cellular map of CW complexes is a CW complex.

Thanks a lot for the help! So my reasoning is, we get that $|\mathrm{Sing}(A)|\subseteq |\mathrm{Sing}(A)|\times [0,1]$ is a CW-subcomplex and (wlog by cellular approximation) that the map $|\mathrm{Sing}(A)|\to |\mathrm{Sing}(X)|$ is cellular, so we can form the pushout of CW-complexes to obtain the mapping cylinder, which again will be a CW complex again by an explicit check on skeleta. Hence we indeed get what we wanted. If you post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

One can replace $A\rightarrow X$ by a map of CW complexes, say by taking $|\mathrm{Sing}(−)|$, and then the mapping cylinder of this gives such a replacement since the induced map is cellular.
